# JQuery Drag to sortable resizes to the containers width in jsfiddle but not in MVC app

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to use JQuery and JQueryUI to create drag to sortable behavior.

I create a POC using fiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/pbjLwcnm/74/

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable:"#child-container",
    helper: "clone",
});

$("#child-container").sortable();
```

The concept works fine (i.e. When I start dragging, the item automatically resizes to the width of sortable) but when I copy paste fiddle code into my MVC app the dragging action resizes the dragging  and upon the drop the it stays small. The difference between fiddle and MVC is different versions of JQuery, fiddle has JQuery 1.9.1 and JQueryUI 1.9.2 while MVC has JQuery v3.3.1 and jQuery UI - v1.12.1. is there a way to force resize of the cloned div so it can fill the container like it is doing in the jsfiddle?

Thanks

Comment: Do you see any Console Errors in your MVC Testing? Please check your Header in the resulting HTML to ensure all the proper CSS and JS are loading. There may be some other conflict too.

Comment: yeah everything loads fine, no console errors, the css and javascript everything is loading